# Use of Myself as a compound subject

Tags: grammar

Myself and my associate, Mr. Gene Curran, are CACI Contractors working for the CERDEC Prototype Integration Facility (PIF) Rapid Prototyping and Technology Insertion Support (RPTIS) program and supporting the Marine Corps G/ATOR program.

Is the use of Myself in the sentence grammatically correct??

Comment: What did you find when you looked up the [use of reflexive pronouns as subjects or objects](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=relfexive+pronouns+as+subjects+or+objects)? How are you using it here?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.  Myself is a "reflexive pronoun."  Reflexive pronouns are used by a speaker(s) to refer to himself or herself (or themselves) as the object of a verb or preposition when he or she is (or they are) also the subject of the clause.  "I love myself."  "I did it to myself."  "He killed himself."  "She did it by herself."  "We blamed ourselves."  "They embarrassed themselves."

The -self pronouns can also be used in an "intensive" to emphasize the subject: “And he, he himself, the Grinch, carved the roast-beast!”  "They themselves are to blame."  "Mary herself solved the problem she had created."  But a -self pronoun cannot stand alone (without the noun or pronoun it refers to) as the subject of a sentence.  (Poetic and literary usages notwithstanding.)

Comment: Nice quotes! +1